# Can you use preg_replace regexp with "not" condition?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm working with SQL strings, and need to replace `"SELECT"` with `"SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS"`.  Because I don't always know what the SQL is, there's potential that it will already have SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS so I need to account for that case, and not match in that case.

This is what I have so far:

> `preg_replace('/(^\s+SELECT)/i', 'SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS',$sql);`

This will return:
`SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM table`

FOR:

> `"\n   SELECT  * from table"`
>
> OR
>
> `"SELECT  * from table"`

I can do:

> `if (! stristr($sql,'SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS') )
>   {
>   // do my replacement
>   }`

But is there a way to do this all in one preg_replace, and/or is it any faster (I expect this will be used quite extensively)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a negative lookahead:

```
/SELECT(?!\s+SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS)/
```